# TypeScriptLab.ts(23,28): error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: javascript, web-services, typescript

I was trying to tsc ts file to js file.I want to input some numbers in texture, and then calculate the mean of those numbers. But here is an error: TypeScriptLab.ts(23,28): error TS1005: ',' expected.

I attached my ts code. Anyone can help please? Thank you so much.

```
import $ from "jquery";

class average{
    constructor(){
        $("#btn").on("click",()=>{
          this.getaverage();
        });
    }

    getaverage():void{ 
        let list:Array<number> = $("textarea").val() as Array<number>;
        let i:number = 0;
        let aver:number =0;
        let sum:number = 0;
        while(i++){
              if (isNaN(list[i])) {
                sum+=list[i];
                aver=sum/(i+1);
              } 
              else
              break;
        }
        $("span").html(aver:number);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll emphathize a bit. When you're new to typescript, and you see that you have to put `:number` in places to say that something is a number, putting yourself in OP's shoes, maybe it would make sense that you might have to do the same when using it too. That's not the case here, but we've all gotta learn, right?

Comment: Did you read the code? I suggest you read all of the content before replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: `$("span").html(aver:number);` Remove the `:number`. You don't have to apply the type syntax when passing variables into other functions.

Comment: When I remove":number",here actually came more errors:TypeScriptLab.ts(11,34): error TS2352: Type 'string | number | string[] | undefined' cannot be converted to type 'number[]'.
  Type 'string[]' is not comparable to type 'number[]'.
    Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'number'.
TypeScriptLab.ts(23,24): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ((this: HTMLElement, index: number, oldhtml: string) => string)'.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to address that error in detail, one second

Comment: Actually, that would probably take too much time to explain properly. It would probably be easier if you did a bit more reading about TypeScript in general from the handbook: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: Note that learning JavaScript itself is important as well, since TS is just JS with types

Answer (score 0):

A bit out of the way, but I was getting this error where I should not be getting the error.  Even updating the version of TS did nothing.  But I had other errors in Lint, so I went through all my code and cleaned it all up and found linting issues upstream from the area that was giving this error.  Once I fixed those - unrelated - issues, these just cleared up.

It appears that Lint is darn good, but not perfect in every way.  As expected.  It is just another tool to be used, at times in context with a little extra troubleshooting.  But I can't complain about this idiosyncrasy because it helped me catch a few errors that would have been extremely difficult to troubleshoot.

The errors I caught were not coming up in Lint, but because Lint triggered near the errors, in relation to the errors, I was able to catch them.   In other words, Lint basically was not able to point directly at my errors, but was able to say "I don't exactly know what's wrong here, but there is something wrong near here."

I don't know if this can help you out in you specific case since in your case it appears to be limited to that small amount of specific code, but I would definitely address any other Lint issues that you are seeing first, then come back to this if you have not already solved it.

If this info does not help you, hopefully it helps someone else Googling the issue months from now.  Good luck.